# Can not query by datatime equal

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Can not be queried by `Staff.where(:year => Date.strptime("2014","%Y")`

But I can get the result with **:year.gte**, but I thought it supposed can be queries by **equal** opearator

```
  Staff.create(
      year: Date.strptime(@year,"%Y"),
  )

    Staff.where(:year => Date.strptime("2014","%Y")
```

Comment: field :year, type: Time

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
field :year, type: Time
```

in a Mongoid model, you end up with a full timestamp (year, month, day, hour, ...) inside MongoDB. When you say:

```
Date.strptime("2014","%Y")
```

in Ruby, you're actually building the *date* `2014-01-01`. That date will be converted to the `2014-01-01T00:00:00` timestamp when you use it to query a `Time` field so you're really doing this:

```
Staff.where(:year => DateTime.parse('2014-01-01T00:00:00'))
```

Presumably you don't have any `2014-01-01T00:00:00` timestamps in your `year` field so that query doesn't find anything.

If you switch to `:year.gte` then you're looking for `year` timestamps that are on or after `2014-01-01T00:00:00` (i.e. anything in 2014, 2015, ...).

I suspect that your `year` field is either badly named or badly typed. If it really is just the year then it should be:

```
field :year, type: Integer
```

and you'd query it with things like:

```
Staff.where(:year => 2014)
```

to get things in 2014. If it really is supposed to be a timestamp then you'd be better off calling it `something_at` (where "something" depends on what time you're really tracking) and you'd usually query it using range operators such as `$gte` and `$lte`.